# Why is the second red point also considered a clockwise crossing on the Nyquist plot?

Tags: nyquist-plot

From [this](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Nyquist/NyquistStability.html) page:

> The image below shows the same Nyquist path, but a different line.  In
> this case there are two clockwise crossings (red) and two
> counterclockwise crossings, for a total of zero encirclements, as
> expected.

It's clear that the first red point on the right is a clockwise crossing. However, how is the second red point also a clockwise crossing?

[image]

Comment: which part of 'clockwise' don't you understand?

Comment: @Neil_UK the second red point from right. It's counter clockwise to me.

Comment: Both red points have the arrow enter from the bottom. Both blue points have the arrow enter from the top. Both red points have the same sign, and the opposite sign to both blue points.

Comment: @Neil_UK both red points have the arrow enter from the bottom but they move in two different direction, one is CW and the other is CCW.

Comment: To me, both paths just change the direction when crossing the black arrow. So it is hard to say on which direction they actually are. (We would need to see the picture zoomed in.)

Comment: You are only interested in the diretion the pth **crosses** the line, not which way it turns immedaiately before or after

Comment: @Neil_UK that makes sense. The page uses CW and CCW when it crosses the line which is confusing.

Comment: @Neil_UK how do you get the information whether there are more number of poles than zero or vice versa with the method of drawng a line like this? You have to consider CW or CCW in order to know that but I don't see how can that be obtained by the method of drawing a line.